# How can I mix Razor and Javascript in a VB project?

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor

I have the following javascript/jquery snippet in a View of my vb.net based asp.net mvc project.  I am trying to hit up the Browse method of my Neutrals controller.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.location.href = '/Neutrals/Browse?AreaOfLaw=' + 
        $('#search_area').val() + '&WebRegionID=' + $('#search_region').val();
</script>
```

I'd like to replace the url string with an @Url.Action, but I can't figure out how to fix the Razor syntax and that of the query parameters that I have.

I've fiddled with it for a good while and most of the time I can't even get it to compile.

Comment: You can concat the client side value to url like '@Url.Action("MethodName", "ControllerName")?SomeParamether=' + value + '&WebRegionID=' + $('#search_region').val();

Answer (score 0):

Use is directly as

```
 window.location.href = '@Url.Action("action","controller")'
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think you can do it.

The problem is that you need those JavaScript variables - i.e. @Url.Action is executed when page is rendered on the server and you don't have JavaScript variables then.

Sure, you can construct part of url on the server, but the querystring part will need to be in JavaScript.